# python - takes 1 positional argument (2 given)

Tags: python, cmd

When I call inform in the python input box, it says I am giving do_inform 2 arguments, but I am only typing "inform" and clicking "OK". Why does it say I am providing two arguments?

```
import cmd

class DisplayWelcome(cmd.Cmd):
    """Welcome user to game"""

    def do_inform(self):
        k = input('Enter a letter')
        print (k)


def main():
    d = DisplayWelcome()
    #d.do_greet()
    d.do_inform()
    d.cmdloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You mean you typed `inform` at the command prompt presented by `cmdloop()`?

Comment: `d` is being passed as a argument

Comment: I think I had a dumb moment. It passes an empty string as an argument when you do not provide one, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes thanks. I've just learnt this today. So I think I read that it will pass an empty string or something empty, if you don't give an argument, then forgot :P

Comment: For the future: In order to debug something like this, it is helpful to modify the function to `def do_inform(self, *a, **k):` and to print `a` and `k` at the top of the function. Then you see what is actually passed to the function and can act appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

All `Cmd.do_*` methods are passed the remainder of the command line, even if empty.

When you type `inform` at the command prompt, the remainder of the line is empty, so `Cmd` calls `self.do_inform('')`.

Always give all of your `do_*` methods an argument for that remainder; you can ignore it if you like:

```
def do_inform(self, rest=None):
    k = input('Enter a letter')
    print (k)
```

The [`cmd` library documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) doesn't make this very clear; is is mentioned at the top of the `cmd.cmdloop()` method documentation:

> Repeatedly issue a prompt, accept input, parse an initial prefix off the received input, and dispatch to action methods, passing them the remainder of the line as argument.